# Java SQLite - Unable to access .db-file inside executable jar

Tags: java, database, maven, sqlite

The database file I want to connect with is located at:

> \ProjectName\src\resources\database\database.db

If I bundle my application into a jar it is located at:

> \ProjectName\target\ProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar\resources\database\database.db

This folder is located in

> C:\Users\Username\Documents\JavaProjects\

My approach in code:

```
private static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:sqlite:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar\\resources\\database\\database.db";

try(final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION)) {
    final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(10);

    statement.executeUpdate(stmt);

    connection.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
 //...
}
```

If I double-click on the `ProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file I get:

> path to
>   C:\Users\Username\Documents\JavaProjects\ProjectName\target\ProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar\resources\database\database.db
>   does not exist.

If I change my connection string to:

> private static final String CONNECTION =
>   "jdbc:sqlite::resource\resources\database\database.db";

then I get:

> path to
>   C:\Users\Username\Documents\JavaProjects\ProjectName\target:resource
>   does not exist

I use maven with this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

How can I access a sqlite-database file inside a .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

According to [documentation](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/Usage.md#reading-database-files-in-classpaths-or-network-read-only) the prefix for classpath database is `jdbc:sqlite::resource:`. Note the semicolon after the resource.

The next problem is that you need to use regular slashes (not backslashes) when you specify package path to file inside the jar.

And the last potential problem is that you need to specify correct package name and file should be packed to jar. What package does the files from `\ProjectName\src\resources` get into? It does not seem that you use default maven structure. You should put the file into `projectRoot/src/main/resources/` given that `pom.xml` is in `projectRoot`. This way maven will put the resource file in the jar.

To sum up, if you put the file to `projectRoot/src/main/resources/database/database.db` the file will get into `database.database` package and the correct JDBC URL would be:

```
jdbc:sqlite::resource:database/database.db
```